# Pubnub on android: class not found

Tags: java, android, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I have imported the jar files. I placed a copy in the libs folder too (just in case). 
I am just trying to subscribe to a channel.

And I get the error: Could not find class 'com.pubnub.api.Pubnub', referenced from method com.melloto.pubnubtest.MainActivity.onCreate

No clue why the error is popping up. 
Thanks in advance

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPvSG.png)

Comment: Have you referenced this libs in your project as libraries? And why you still use eclipse? The default gradle setup would automaticly include all jars inside the libs folder.

Comment: Thank you Rene. I got it up and running
I am using eclipse because I am kinda used to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register all library jar files in your project settings. Otherwise eclipse and adt will not use them.